# How do I improve my presentation skills in the seminar?

Tags: college, explaining, self-esteem, tasks, presentation

I am an engineering student and I have to prepare seminars frequently. Seminars count for the marks scored and credit. I'm given a topic, I prepare it thoroughly and make a good content slide.

*All my problems occur while delivering the seminar speech.* I end the seminars without the audience understanding much. I just can't speak properly on stage. How can I improve my presentation skills?

(I can help my friends understand the same topics clearly.)

Comment: Welcome to IPS! Unfortunately, right now your question is a little bit broad (which makes it not a great fit for this site), but I think we can narrow it down a bit and make it into a very good question for IPS. Is there a particular skill related to speaking on stage that you are having trouble with?

Comment: Maybe you can check some useful answers [HERE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/1087/how-can-i-calm-myself-down-when-giving-a-presentation/)?

Comment: @OldPadawan found some useful answers there too

Comment: There are public speaking courses and coaching which might be helpful. Unfortunately (for the purposes of this post, at least) public speaking like this isn't really an interpersonal skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public speaking is undoubtedly an interpersonal skill. There is no downside to acquiring it. Lots of practice with safe audiences is essential. If you have money to splash around you can pay people to train you, but it is cheaper and better to seek opportunities to practice, at first outside your professional career. There is a huge amount of free advice online. The more you do it, the more confident you will become, and the more confident you become, the better a public speaker you will be.

I am now a confident public speaker because I have done it lots of times. When I started I was tongue-tied and inarticulate.